# Why is the download of a URL in Java so slow?

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-s3, url, download

I have a Java application, in which I need to download the content of an S3 presigned URL to a file to disk.

However, I have experienced **slow download speeds** when downloading from the URL.

#### Experiment

I created an experiment, where I put my Java code and a comparable Node.JS code on an AWS Lambda. Both Lambdas were configured equally in terms of memory, region and ephemeral storage size. This was done to eliminate other environment variables such as disk I/O and networking.

**Lambda Runtime:** Java 17 / NodeJS 18

**Lambda Architecture:** x86_64

**Lambda OS:** Amazon Linux 2

#### Java Code

To download from the URL, I am using the java non-blocking NIO library. In a nutshell, this is what my download looks like:

```
URL url = new URL("MY_S3_PRESIGNED_URL");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
try (final InputStream is = new InputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     final FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
    os.getChannel().transferFrom(Channels.newChannel(is), 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

#### NodeJS Code

This is what my Node.js code looks like:

```
async function getObject() {
    let url = "MY_S3_PRESIGNED_URL"
    
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let responseDataChunks = [];
        
        https.get(url, response => {
            
            response.once('error', err => reject(err));

            response.on('data', chunk => responseDataChunks.push(chunk));
            
            response.once('end', () => resolve('done'));
        }) 
    })
}
```

#### Experiment Results

I invoked both lambdas with an S3 presigned URL to a 700MB file. These were my average download speed results:

**Java**: 36 seconds

**NodeJS**: 8 seconds

#### Question

**How can I improve the download speed in Java?** I followed the suggestion in the baeldung article for downloading from a URL in Java. ([Ref](https://www.baeldung.com/java-download-file))

The article suggests using Apache Commons IO or NIO library. However, neither of these approaches helped my download speed.

I would appreciate any suggestions, thank you!

#### What I've Tried

Why is the NodeJS download so much quicker? I have tried multiple things in Java trying to speed up the download, such as

- Using **ranged gets** ([Ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/s3-optimizing-performance-best-practices/use-byte-range-fetches.html)).
- Using `FileUtils.copyURLToFile` from Apache Commons IO.
- Using a **BufferedInputStream** instead of the InputStream currently shown in the Java Code. I tried different buffer sizes.

None of the actions listed improved my download by any significant margin.

Comment: The bottleneck simply isn't VM execution speed. Hence, that wouldn't explain it. failure to use buffers can, but you generally get a bigger difference than an 8x factor, and you've tried wrapping stuff in buffers. From your node code it's not clear where the data is going. Step 1 is to eliminate elements. Eliminate your disk; instead of saving the content to disk, hash it (this ensures the data cannot be optimized away, though I doubt that's an issue here, and eliminates disk access).

Comment: I would give `try (final InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream(), 8 * 1024 * 1024);
     final OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file), 8 * 1024 * 1024)) {` a try.

Comment: For example, if you've been wrapping your __input__ stream in a buffer, but not the output, that can definitely introduce slowdowns that are trivially eliminated by wrapping the `FileOutputStream` into a buffer.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Thanks! I eliminated the disk, by loading the entire file into memory using `inputStream.readAllBytes();` and I was writing nothing to the disk at all. The lambda has 5 GB of memory configured.

The download still took 40 seconds.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thanks for the suggestion! The only issue with that is, that the BufferdOutputStream class does not provide any method for getting the channel, so I cannot use the NIO library. 

Nevertheless, I tried writing to the BufferdOutputStream "manually", but it did not help in speed. The download was around 45 seconds. I believe NIO's implementation is actually quicker.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, but according to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom-java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel-long-long-) for `transferFrom` doing a single transfer of `Long.MAX_VALUE` does not guarantee to transfer all of the bytes.  What you should do (strictly speaking) is test the result of `transferFrom` and handle it as you would a regular `InputStream.read(byte[])` call.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what platform (OS and Java version) your client is running on.  Among other things, the performance of `transferFrom` depends on the underlying OS ... and its ability to do direct transfers.

Comment: You may also want to try `HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(HttpRequest.newBuilder(url.toURI()).GET().build(), HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofFile(file.toPath()));`.  See [the package docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/package-summary.html) and [the module docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.net.http/module-summary.html) for details.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but what kind of URL do  you use? Is it `https://…`? If so, then you compare apples and pears. And you should check the comment from @VGR!

Comment: Perhaps try a one-liner using *Java HTTP Client*, as shown in [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76050505/642706)

Comment: @StephenC this is a really great callout and likely related to another issue I am seeing. (Cutoff downloads). Thank you!

Also I have added the Java version of the lambda to the question (17). I don't control the OS, since Lambda is a managed service.

Comment: @VGR I tried this exactly thank you! The download however still took 45 seconds.

Comment: @tquadrat The URL is always `https://`. Could this explain something?

Comment: What is your approximate bandwidth?  Is it possible node.js is using a cache?  (Actually, I’m surprised Java isn’t using a cache.)

Comment: @VGR I‘m not sure exactly of the bandwidth in Lambda, since that is once again abstracted away for you. I would be surprised if the bandwidth was the issue. 

Not sure about the cache, what would it cache? If I give both of them a never-before-seen presigned URL of 700MB size, the performance is identical. (java takes very long while Nodejs is quick)

Comment: If the protocol is HTTP(S), you should also check the behaviour of the WebServer on the other side. It may respond differently to the clients that connect to it. Also the different protocol settings that are sent (or not sent) to that server can have a significant impact on the performance. The node.js approach clearly is a http connection (that can be/is configured properly), but the standard URL connection is using some defaults that should work for every case. Therefore you should look for the suggestion from @VGR again and see if it does not have some nut and bolts  for optimisation.

Comment: And perhaps you should change the experiment to store to your local disc, so that you can use a network sniffer on your side. Seeing what happens on the wire may help to understand what's going on.